# How to convert dd/mm to Mysql Datetime format in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a date string with `dd/mm` format like `06/03`.Now i have to store this string into mysql table column with `DATETIME` format.

I am getting the problem as How can i add the current year generically because i don't want to hard code it.Subsequently how will i convert it into MySql `DATETIME` format for saving it.

Please help me .

Comment: what do you mean "add the current year generically" ?

Comment: @Noctis By this i mean that i dont want to give year details like `2014` manually.I want program to get the current year and append into the date string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Parse**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) method of DateTime:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("06/03");
```

---

**UPDATE**

For your comment:

> Also after parsing into DateTime i am getting date correct but time i
>   dont want to be 12:00:00 AM instead i want it to be 00:00:00.

`12:00:00 AM` corresponds to `00:00:00` only. You can verify that by getting `Hour` property which will return 0 and also `TimeOfDay` will too return `00:00:00`.

Even if you try to parse exact date, it also creates the same format.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("06/03 00:00:00", "dd/MM hh:mm:ss", 
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And you don't need conversion from DateTime object to SQL compliant DateTime object. You can pass the .Net object to SQL writer.

Comment: OK and how i should convert it into Mysql DATETIME format

Comment: Also after parsing into `DateTime` i am getting date correct but time i dont want to be `12:00:00 AM` instead i want it to be `00:00:00`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the code:
C#

```
    string s = "06/03";
    System.DateTime dateNow = Convert.ToDateTime(s);
```

will give the output as you required

in VB.Net :

```
Dim s As String = "06/03"
Dim dateNow As Date = CDate(s)
MsgBox(dateNow)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
var some_date = "06/03";
var year = DateTime.Now.Year;

var option = some_date+"/"+year;
```

Or use any of the string formats to bend it to your needs

More on date string format can be found on [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page.

---

**Edit**:

If you want zeroes in the time, like your comment said, you can usit Rohit vats answer and do:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("06/03");
var s1 = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yy 00:00:00");
// Output: 03/06/14 00:00:00
var s2 = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy 00:00:00");
// Output: 03/06/2014 00:00:00
```

Comment: Ok But my format is `dd/MM`.please see the post and here it is MM/dd.It is converting date into month and vice versa

Comment: Swap `MM/dd` to `dd/MM` on the `ToString()`. I can update the answer if you want, but the output will change according to your formatting, and the MSDN page has all the bells and options you might want or need :)

Comment: OK .One More query how can i send to mysql DATETIME format